# Other method for finding the equations of the electric field lines

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, vector-fields, calculus

I have an electric potential which, through separation of variables, can be written as $$\phi (x,y)= X(x) \cdot Y(y) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty Cn\cdot \cos(k_n x)\cdot \sinh (k_n y)$$
with $C_n $ and $k_n$ constants which come from my boundary conditions. To find the equations for the electric field lines, we can use the fact that:
$$\frac{d x}{E_x}=\frac{d y}{E_y}$$
But since the electric potential is written in terms of an infinite sum, the outcome for $y(x)$, after calculating $E_x$ and $E_y$ and eliminating the constants, would be: 
$$y(x)=\int \frac{Ey}{Ex}dx=\int \frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin(k_nx)\sinh(k_ny)}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos(k_nx)\cosh(k_ny)}dx$$
Which seems impossible to inegrate. 
Is there another way to get the equations of the electric field lines in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\frac{dy}{dx}$  gives us the variation of the curves throughout the plane, we can use it to analysize the electric field lines without finding the full equations.

By evaluating the differential, $\frac{dy}{dx}$, at the system's boundary points, we can then use that information to try to map the electric field lines and verify our results by confronting them with the frontier-conditions.

Eventhough this doesn't allow us to solve the problem analytically, it gives a good insight into how the electric field lines behave.

Alternatively, we can use the information about the electric field itself to map the lines using Python or other programming software.